# Rich Text Editing in Silverlight 2

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0

We've looked in Silverlight 2 recently and found no way to edit formatted text there. Is this really true, and are there any (maybe commercial) external rich text editors available?

Answer (score 2):

Vectorlight has a [rich text box](http://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight_rich_textbox_demo.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself yet but this is one I know of.

http://www.codeplex.com/richtextedit

Comment: this project does not appear to be active anymore

Answer (score 1):

ComponentOne also has a RichTextBox control in the works:

http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/RichTextBoxSilverlight/